# Managing multiple calendar event intents

Tags: android, android-intent, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I'm trying to implement multiple intents to add events to the calendar.

For a single event I use something similar to the following code:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT); intent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Some Test Event");
intent.putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, true); intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, cal.getTime().getTime()); intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, cal.getTime().getTime() + 600000);    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,      "attendee1@yourtest.com, attendee2@yourtest.com");
startActivity(intent);
```

This code works great, but when it comes to more than one intent it fails. If you change **intent** to an **intentArray** and then you use a for loop for starting the activities or just **startActivities(intentArray);** it will have some weird behaviour depending on the calendar app installed on the device.

For samsung default calendar apps, it will work great. But for Google Calendar, it will show the last intent from the array first and then it will skip one intent and show the rest in order.

For example, if the intent array is filled with i1, i2, i3, ... in, the app will launch activity in, and then i1, i2, i3... until i(n-2).

Can someone help me with this issue??
Alternative code will also be really helpful!

Comment: You unfortunately can't control how apps handle "open" intents like the `Intent.ACTION_INSERT`. In your case, maybe you will need to control manually the multiple insertions one by one: start the activity for the first event, then on `onActivityResult()`, start it for the next event and so on.

Comment: So this issue may be some kind of "bug" from Google? Could you give me an example of how to insert them using ``onActivityResult()``?

Comment: This could be a bug of the Google Calendar, since you say it works with the Samsung one. You are not going to insert the event on `onActivityResult()`. On that method, you check if the `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK`, and if it is, you can call the `Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)` for the next event you want the calendar app to insert for you.